# Prove an interesting property of pdf moments?

Tags: probability-distributions

I am examining properties of mass moments of probability densities:

$$ m_{i}\equiv\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^{i}f\left(x\right)dx  $$

Define a $\,n\times n\,$ covariance of the first $\,n\,$ moments:

$$ M_{ij}\equiv\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f\left(x\right)\left(x^{i}-m_{i}\right)\left(x^{j}-m_{j}\right)dx=m_{i+j}-m_{i}m_{j} $$
where $1\leq i\leq n$ and $1\leq j\leq n$

I suspect but have failed to prove that:

$$ \left|M_{n\times n}\right|=0\iff\left\{ \begin{array}{c}
f\left(x\right)=\frac{1}{r}\sum_{j=1}^{r}\delta\left(x-x_{j}\right)\\
r\leq n\end{array}\right\} $$

In other words if $M$ is $n\times n$ and its Determinant is $0$, then $f(x)$ is a set of $n$ or fewer spikes.
If $f(x)$ has more than $n$ spikes or has any continuous portion then $|M|>0$ for all $n$.

It's easy enough to demonstrate for chosen values of $r$ that $|M|=0$ ; the Mathematica code below does that. But I need a proof that if $\,|M|=0$ , then $\,f(x)\,$ consists of $\,r\,$ spikes, where $\,r\le n$ .

```
(*Demonstrate that for any n, Det[M]==0 if r==n, Det[M]>0 if r>n *)

n = 4;
M = Table[m[i + j] - m[i]*m[j], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}];
Print[n, "-particle Det = ", Det[M] /. m[q_] -> (Sum[x[i]^q, {i, 1, n}]/n) // Simplify];
Print[n + 1, "-particle Det = ", Det[M] /. m[q_] -> (Sum[x[i]^q, {i, 1, n + 1}]/(n + 1)) // Simplify];
```

Comment: Maybe you can use the fact that $m[j]=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{x_i^j}{n}$.

Comment: @Bernhard  Yes, that's exactly what I do in the demo code.  It demonstrates that Det[M] is zero for whatever value of n you use, but I need a general proof that this is true for all n.

Comment: @Bernhard I just posted a bounty on this Quesiton

Comment: Do the zeroth moments count as well? I mean, is: $0\le i$ and $0\le j$ ?

Comment: @HandeBruijn Not sure what you meant, but f(x) is a pdf, so the 0th moment is just 1.

Comment: And those $1$'s are not in the matrix, right?

Comment: @HandeBruijn Correct.  1 <= j <= n.  I will edit to clarify that.  Thanks.

Comment: @HandeBruijn  You probably get asked this a lot... Are you related to Niclaas Govert de Bruijn? I did genome assembly work with de Bruijn Graphs, and de Bruijn's Identity is essential in my current work.

Comment: @JerryGuern: No, he is not a relative of mine. But I'm proud to say that he has been one of my professors at the Eindhoven University of Technology, among other excellent people, like Edsger Dijkstra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's false as stated: the determinant should be $0$ for any $f$ that is supported on a set of cardinality $\le n$, not just a uniform distribution.
In fact, let $X$ be a random variable whose distribution is supported on a set $\{r_1, \ldots, r_n\}$ of cardinality $n$.  Let
$P(z) = \prod_{k=1}^n (z - r_k) = \sum_{j=0}^n a_j z^j$.
If ${\bf a} = (a_1, \ldots, a_n)^T$, then $P(X) = 0$ so 
$(M {\bf a})_j = \text{Cov}(X^j, P(X)) = 0$ (the lack of an $a_0$ term does not matter because $\text{Cov}(X^j, 1) = 0$)
and therefore $M$ is singular.

Conversely, if $M$ is singular, take ${\bf b} \ne 0$ in its null space, and
define $P(z) = \sum_{k=1}^n b_j z^j$.  We have 
$\text{Var}(P(X)) = \text{Cov}(P(X),P(X)) = {\bf b}^T M {\bf b} = 0$, 
which implies $P(X) = 0$ a.s., and that means $X$ is almost surely one of the roots of $P$ (of which there are at most $n$).

Comment: A very dense answer!  Thank you.  I gather that you're saying M will be singular even if the spikes in the pdf have unequal weight. But I'm struggling with this step in your explanation: $(M {\bf a})_j = \text{Cov}(X^j, P(X)) = 0$.  Could you give that a bit of explanation?  Also, I'm not certain if your answer proves $M_{n\times n}$ is non-singular if f(x) has more than n spikes.

Comment: Covariance is bilinear, so $\text{Cov}(X^j, P(X)) = \sum_{k=0}^n a_k \text{Cov}(X^j, X^k) = \sum_{k=1}^n M_{jk} a_k = (M {\bf a})_j$.

Comment: Thank you!  It took me some time to understand this, hence the delay in awarding the bounty.

Comment: I posted a more baby-steps version of this answer below.

Comment: One more small question. What does "almost surely" mean in math? I can't even find a good online explanation, and I've looked.

Comment: It means "with probability $1$".

Comment: I posted another bounty question that might be up your alley.  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1455526/how-to-solve-an-integral-with-a-gaussian-mixture-denominator

Answer (score 1):

I posted the Question and awarded the bounty to @RobertIsrael for his great Answer above. But I had to think pretty hard about his answer and "translate" into simpler language for myself, so I thought I'd post my simpler version.

First of all, my assertion wasn't quite correct because the spikes in the pdf $f(x)$ can be differently weighted. So the corrected theorem is:

$$ \left|M_{n\times n}\right|=0\iff\left\{ \begin{array}{c}
f\left(x\right)=\sum_{j=1}^{r}w_{j}\delta\left(x-x_{j}\right)\\
r\leq n\end{array}\right\}  $$

Since any weight can be zero, the case where there are fewer than n spikes is covered. The RHS of the above eqn can be restated as:

$$ f\left(x\notin\left\{ x_{1},...,x_{n}\right\} \right)=0 $$

Now consider this n-th order polynomial:

$$ q\left(x\right)\equiv\prod_{j=1}^{n}\left(x-x_{j}\right)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_{k}x^{k}$$

It is trivial but not necessary to calculate the $a_k$'s. For any x, either $f(x)$ or $q(x)$ will equal 0. Therefore, the following integrand and integral both equal zero:

$$ 0=\int f\left(x\right)\left(x^{j}-m_{j}\right)q\left(x\right)dx=\int f\left(x\right)\left(x^{j}-m_{j}\right)\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_{n}x^{k}dx=\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_{n}\left(m_{j+k}-m_{j}m_{k}\right)=\left(M_{n\times n}a\right)_{j} $$

This proves that $a$ is a 0-eigenvector of M, which can only occur if M is singular, QED:
$$ f\left(x\notin\left\{ x_{1},...,x_{n}\right\} \right)=0\Rightarrow|M_{n\times n}|=0 $$

Proof of the converse: If $M$ is singular, then there exists some $a\neq0$ such that $Ma=0$, from which we can construct a polynomial $q\left(x\right)\equiv\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_{k}x^{k}$, the covariance of which is:

$$Cov\left(q\left(x\right)\right)=\int f\left(x\right)\left(q\left(x\right)-\left\langle q\left(x\right)\right\rangle \right)^{2}=\int f\left(x\right)\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_{k}\left(x^{k}-m_{k}\right)\right)^{2}=a^{T}Ma=0$$

$Cov(q(x))=0$ implies that $f(x)=0$ whenever $q(x)\neq0$, i.e., $f(x)$ can only be non-zero at the n roots of $q(x)$, QED:

$$|M_{n\times n}|=0\Rightarrow f\left(x\notin\left\{ x_{1},...,x_{n}\right\} \right)=0$$

...which completes the proof.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the up-vote.  I'm glad to know someone found this extra explanation helpful.